# Google Spreadsheet to SSIS VB Code issue

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript, ssis, visual-studio-2015

*Requirement*:
Convert Google Spreadsheet data to SQL Server through SSIS.

*Method:*
With help from [this](http://sqldeveloperramblings.blogspot.in/2010/06/ssis-google-spreadsheets-data-source.html) website, I'm doing coding in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. I have prepared Variables, Control Flow, Data Flow and added Script component and the required Google References.

*Code pasted in VS as Visual Basic 2015:*

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Imports System.Math

Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper

Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
Imports Google.GData.Client

Imports Google.GData.Extensions

Imports Google.GData.Spreadsheets

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> 'Line 15 Error here

<CLSCompliant(False)> 'Line 17 Error here

Public Class ScriptMain

    Inherits UserComponent

    Dim objListFeed As ListFeed

    Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()

        MyBase.PreExecute()


        Dim objService As SpreadsheetsService
        Dim objWorkSheetQuery As WorksheetQuery

        Dim objWorkSheetFeed As WorksheetFeed
        Dim objWorkSheet As WorksheetEntry

        Dim objListFeedLink As AtomLink
        Dim objListQuery As ListQuery

        Dim bt(0) As Byte

        'Create a connection to the google account 

        objService = New SpreadsheetsService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1")

        Me.Log(Variables.strPassword, 0, bt)

        Me.Log(Variables.strUserName, 0, bt)

        objService.setUserCredentials(Variables.strUserName, Variables.strPassword)

        Me.Log("Service: " + Variables.strUserName, 0, bt)


        'Connect to a specific spreadsheet 

        objWorkSheetQuery = New WorksheetQuery(Variables.strKey, "private", "full")

        objWorkSheetFeed = objService.Query(objWorkSheetQuery)

        objWorkSheet = objWorkSheetFeed.Entries(0)

        Me.Log("Spreadsheet: " + objWorkSheet.Title.Text.ToString, 0, bt)

        'Get a list feed of all the rows in the spreadsheet 

        objListFeedLink = objWorkSheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, Nothing)

        objListQuery = New ListQuery(objListFeedLink.HRef.ToString())
        objListFeed = objService.Query(objListQuery)

        Me.Log("ListFeed: " + objListFeed.Feed.ToString, 0, bt)

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()

        MyBase.PostExecute()

    End Sub


    Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

        Dim objRow As ListEntry

        For Each objRow In objListFeed.Entries

            With Output0Buffer

                .AddRow()

                .Product = objRow.Elements.Item(0).Value

                .Qty = objRow.Elements.Item(1).Value



            End With

        Next


        Output0Buffer.EndOfRowset()

    End Sub

End Class
```

*Problem:*
Upon pressing Build, I get the following error on Line 15 and 17.

> BC32035  VB.NET Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a
>   line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a94dchz0(v=vs.90).aspx) it says to add a space and underscore following the attribute, however, when I add them they are just automatically removed.

Comment: What if you try putting them all on one line?

Comment: I combined Line 15 and 17 still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new script component in a new SSIS package dataflow, and here are the lines between the import block and the Class declaration:

```
' This is the class to which to add your code.  Do not change the name, attributes, or parent
' of this class.
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent
```

I have never heard of the situation you describe where the underscores just "disappear", but maybe if you paste these lines over your lines it will work.

If not, you may need to copy your code to the clipboard, and then destroy the script component and create a new one, and paste your code into it.

Comment: Thanks Tab, I was deleting all code and pasting from website. After your advise - I just add the new code in existing and it works. Thanks